# Atribuir valor ao input text

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

tenho o código abaixo que esta funcionando perfeito, ou seja, sempre que movimento as imagens me aparece as escalas de left e top das mesmas.
Porém esta aparecendo com LI e eu preciso que apareça no VALUE de um INPUT TYPE=TEXT, pois preciso enviar o resultado para  banco de dados via PHP e MYSQL.

Se os amigos puderem me ajudar, ficarei muito grato.

Abraços a todos.

jQuery

```
$('#img').draggable({
    drag: function () {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var xPos = offset.left;
        var yPos = offset.top;
        $('#posX').text('Hori: ' + xPos);
        $('#posY').text('Vert: ' + yPos);
    }
});

});
```

HTML

```
    <li id="posX">Hori: 0</li>
    <li id="posY">Vert: 0</li>
```

Answer (score 3):

Teste assim, ao invés de utilizar a função `.text()` use a `.val()`:

```
$('#img').draggable({
    drag: function () {
        var offset = $(this).offset();
        var xPos = offset.left;
        var yPos = offset.top;

        $('#posX').val('Hori: ' + xPos);
        $('#posY').val('Vert: ' + yPos);
    }
});
```

HTML troque os `li` para `input` com o mesmo id:

```
<input type="text" id="posX" />
<input type="text" id="posY" />
```

Comment: Valeu Mastria, funcionou na boa.
Muito obrigado pela dica.

Comment: @MuriloCabral se funcionou marque como correta a resposta para que outras pessoas sejam beneficiadas em pesquisas futuras. :)